# Connecting to ms exchange shared mailbox via imaps using apache camel fails with error AUTHENTICATE failed

Tags: spring, apache-camel, uri, exchange-server, imap

Were running Apache Camel (2.25.2) and connecting to mailboxes via imaps.
Our configuration works but not for shared mailboxes. Connect string we use to connect "normal" mailbox:

```
imaps://srv.Domain:993?username=UserMb@Domain&password=Pass&folderName=Inbox&consumer.delay=60000&copyTo=done&delete=true&mail.imap.starttls.enable=true&mapMailMessage=true
```

This works fine. Camel is able to read/copy etc. mails from inbox and other folders.
For connecting to shared mailbox we use same string only adjusting **username=**.

For example:

```
imaps://srv.Domain:993?username=UserMb@Domain\UserMb2&password=Pass&folderName=Inbox&...
```

.. and it is not working.

Ive already tried Domain\UserMb\UserMb2 or UserMb@Domain\UserMb2@Domain or UserMb@Domain\UserMb2 etc.
and also

```
imaps://UserMb@Domain:Pass@srv.Domain:993?folderName=Inbox...
```

All works fine for UserMb until shared mailbox UserMb2 is added.

Ive also rechecked in Thunderbird, mapping UserMb2 as shared mailbox using **UserMb@Domain\UserMb2@Domain** which works fine.

Ive already read something similiar here [Possible to connect with a Microsoft Exchange shared mailbox via service account using JavaMail and Apache Camel Mail (IMAP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43661682/possible-to-connect-with-a-microsoft-exchange-shared-mailbox-via-service-account) but without a correct solution for us.

Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you quote that backslash correctly?

Comment: I think so. ive been trying different ways (double backslash, %5C and also single one).
Domain\UserMb works, for UserMb2 not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching found https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-9355
Adding

```
mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable=true&mail.imaps.auth.ntlm.disable=true&mail.imaps.auth.gssapi.disable=true
```

solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

To Access Shared mailbox via IMAP with Camel-mail 2.x.x and Java-mail-1.6.x :

Parameters:

- username=SERVICE_ACCOUNT_USERNAME
- password=PASSWORD
- mail.imaps.sasl.authorizationid=SHARED_MAILBOX_ALIAS
- mail.imap.auth.plain.disable=true
- mail.imap.auth.ntlm.disable=true
- mail.imap.auth.gssapi.disable=true

Example:

`<from uri="imaps://outlook.office365.com?  username=XYZ@DOMAIN.COM&password=PASSWORD&mail.imap.auth.plain.disable=true&mail.imap.auth.ntlm.disable=true&mail.imap.auth.gssapi.disable=true&mail.imaps.sasl.authorizationid=SHARED_MAILBOX_ALIAS" />`